# PHP 7 Warning: Unexpected character in input: '

Tags: php, oracle, function, syntax-error, runtime-error

Every time I run a function in this file, no matter the function even if its just included in another file, the following error keeps popping up, and I can't seem to identify the piece of code that is breaking it.

When I remove a function the same error shows up on a totally different line.

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in
>   Z:\WEB\cgit\functions\tools.php on line 125

```
<?php
    function connect() {
        $conn = oci_connect($username, $password, 'localhost:1521/xe');
        if (!$conn) {
            $e = oci_error();
            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
        } else return $conn;
    } //end connect
    // /Used to check if a row with the specified value exist in a table
    // /INPUT $attribute: index name in $_GET or $_POST
    // /INPUT $table: name of table in database
    // /INPUT $column: name of column to check against in database
    // /INPUT $getOrpost: specifies where the data is stored, options:$_GET or $_POST
    function CheckExist($attribute, $table, $column, $getOrpost) {
        if (isset($getOrpost)) {
            if (!empty($getOrpost) && !empty($getOrpost[$attribute])) {
                $input = htmlspecialchars($getOrpost[$attribute]);
                $pdo = connect();
                $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(' . $column . ') FROM ' . $table . ' where ' . $column . ' = :attribute';
                $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
                oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':attribute', $input);
                if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
                    $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
                    if ($res['COUNT(' . $column . ')'] != 0) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $e = oci_error($prepare);
                    echo $e['message'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function CheckExistExt($attribute, $table, $column, $wherecolumn) {
        if (isset($attribute)) {
            if (!empty($attribute)) {
                $input = htmlspecialchars($attribute);
                $pdo = connect();
                $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(' . $column . ') FROM ' . $table . ' where ' . $wherecolumn . ' = :attribute';
                $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
                oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':attribute', $input);
                if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
                    $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
                    if ($res['COUNT(' . $column . ')'] != 0) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $e = oci_error($prepare);
                    echo $e['message'];
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // /Used to return single cell from database
    // /INPUT $table: table in the database where to look for the data
    // /INPUT $column: the name of the column you want to select
    // /INPUT $where_column: the name of the column that contains the data that needs to match the input
    // /INPUT $where: the data that will be looked for in the specified column.
    function GrabData($table, $column, $where_column, $where) {
        $input = $where;
        $pdo = connect();
        $sql = 'SELECT ' . $column . ' FROM ' . $table . ' where ' . $where_column . ' = :attribute';
        $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
        oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':attribute', $input);
        if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
            $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
            if ($res != null) {
                return $res;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $e = oci_error($prepare);
            echo $e['message'];
        }
    }
    // /Used to return the results of a specified mySQL query
    // /$query is the basic mySQL query eg: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password".
    // /$bind is a nested array, must be in pairs, eg: 'array(array(':email', 'generic@email.com'), array(':password', 'passwordtext'))'
    function GrabMoreData($query, $bind = null) {
        $pdo = connect();
        $sql = $query;
        $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
        if (!empty($bind)) {
            foreach ($bind as $attribute) {
                oci_bind_by_name($prepare, $attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
                /*                                 echo $attribute[0]." ".$attribute[1];*/
            }
        }
        if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
            $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
            if ($res != null) {
                return $res;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $e = oci_error($prepare);
            echo $e['message'];
        }
    }
    function GrabAllData($query, $bind = null) {
        $pdo = connect();
        $sql = $query;
        $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
        if (!empty($bind)) {
            foreach ($bind as $attribute) {
                oci_bind_by_name($prepare, $attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
            }
        }
        if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
            oci_fetch_all($prepare, $res);
            if ($res != null) {
                return $res;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $e = oci_error($prepare);
            echo $e['message'];
        }
    }
    function InsertData($query, $bind = null) {
        $pdo = connect();
        $sql = $query;
        $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
        if (!empty($bind)) {
            foreach ($bind as $attribute) {
                oci_bind_by_name($prepare, $attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
            }
        }
        if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
            return 'success';
        } else {
            $e = oci_error($prepare);
            echo $e['message'];
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You must have forgot the end quote or semi-colon somewhere in your code.

Comment: Nooooo..... this sort of programming is just right for performing SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I solved it!
At end of the code after class curly bracket you might be clear surplus lines and PHP ending tag `?>`.

```
<?php
function connect() {
    $conn = oci_connect($username, $password, 'localhost:1521/xe');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    } else return $conn;
} //end connect
// /Used to check if a row with the specified value exist in a table
// /INPUT $attribute: index name in $_GET or $_POST
// /INPUT $table: name of table in database
// /INPUT $column: name of column to check against in database
// /INPUT $getOrpost: specifies where the data is stored, options:$_GET or $_POST
function CheckExist($attribute, $table, $column, $getOrpost) {
    if (isset($getOrpost)) {
        if (!empty($getOrpost) && !empty($getOrpost[$attribute])) {
            $input = htmlspecialchars($getOrpost[$attribute]);
            $pdo = connect();
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(' . $column . ') FROM ' . $table . ' where ' . $column . ' = :attribute';
            $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
            oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':attribute', $input);
            if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
                $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
                if ($res['COUNT(' . $column . ')'] != 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $e = oci_error($prepare);
                echo $e['message'];
            }
        }
    }
}
function CheckExistExt($attribute, $table, $column, $wherecolumn) {
    if (isset($attribute)) {
        if (!empty($attribute)) {
            $input = htmlspecialchars($attribute);
            $pdo = connect();
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(' . $column . ') FROM ' . $table . ' where ' . $wherecolumn . ' = :attribute';
            $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
            oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':attribute', $input);
            if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
                $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
                if ($res['COUNT(' . $column . ')'] != 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $e = oci_error($prepare);
                echo $e['message'];
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
// /Used to return single cell from database
// /INPUT $table: table in the database where to look for the data
// /INPUT $column: the name of the column you want to select
// /INPUT $where_column: the name of the column that contains the data that needs to match the input
// /INPUT $where: the data that will be looked for in the specified column.
function GrabData($table, $column, $where_column, $where) {
    $input = $where;
    $pdo = connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT ' . $column . ' FROM ' . $table . ' where ' . $where_column . ' = :attribute';
    $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':attribute', $input);
    if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
        $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
        if ($res != null) {
            return $res;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $e = oci_error($prepare);
        echo $e['message'];
    }
}
// /Used to return the results of a specified mySQL query
// /$query is the basic mySQL query eg: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password".
// /$bind is a nested array, must be in pairs, eg: 'array(array(':email', 'generic@email.com'), array(':password', 'passwordtext'))'
function GrabMoreData($query, $bind = null) {
    $pdo = connect();
    $sql = $query;
    $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
    if (!empty($bind)) {
        foreach ($bind as $attribute) {
            oci_bind_by_name($prepare, $attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
            /*                                 echo $attribute[0]." ".$attribute[1];*/
        }
    }
    if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
        $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
        if ($res != null) {
            return $res;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $e = oci_error($prepare);
        echo $e['message'];
    }
}
function GrabAllData($query, $bind = null) {
    $pdo = connect();
    $sql = $query;
    $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
    if (!empty($bind)) {
        foreach ($bind as $attribute) {
            oci_bind_by_name($prepare, $attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
        }
    }
    if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
        oci_fetch_all($prepare, $res);
        if ($res != null) {
            return $res;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $e = oci_error($prepare);
        echo $e['message'];
    }
}
function InsertData($query, $bind = null) {
    $pdo = connect();
    $sql = $query;
    $prepare = oci_parse($pdo, $sql);
    if (!empty($bind)) {
        foreach ($bind as $attribute) {
            oci_bind_by_name($prepare, $attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
        }
    }
    if (oci_execute($prepare)) {
        return 'success';
    } else {
        $e = oci_error($prepare);
        echo $e['message'];
    }
}
```